How to Sync Files Between Local Machine and Kubernetes Pod on Save in VSCode without using Git?
I need to synchronize my local files with a pod every time I save a file in VSCode. To add more context, I am running machine learning training (and evals/inference) and there at the very minimum, if I can sync my files with the shared file system in the kubernetes cluster -- that would be good enough for me. Of course, something more general as I know kubernetes has thousands of containers running likely for other use cases like serving web services etc. that would be good too. Here are the constraints and approaches I have considered:
Constraints:

I want to use VSCode to push changes on save.
I cannot use GitHub, GitLab, or perform any git push operations on the pod.
I can get the pod's IP address using kubectl get pods -o wide | grep username.

Approaches Considered:

Using VSCode's RSYNC Extension:

I am considering using the VSCode RSYNC extension to push changes automatically on save.
Example settings.json configuration for Sync-Rsync:
{
  "rsync.target": "user@pod-ip:/path/to/remote/folder",
  "rsync.onSave": true,
  "rsync.direction": "upload",
  "rsync.flags": "-avz"
}


However, I'm not sure how to set up the SSH server inside the pod and expose the SSH port.


Using kubectl cp Command:

Another approach is to run kubectl cp ~/python_repo/ pod_name:/data/username/ every time I save a file in VSCode.
I could create a script (sync.sh) and use a file watcher to run this command automatically.
Example sync.sh script:
#!/bin/bash
LOCAL_DIR="/path/to/local/folder"
POD_NAME="pod-name"
REMOTE_DIR="/data/username/"
kubectl cp $LOCAL_DIR $POD_NAME:$REMOTE_DIR


Using a file watcher like entr to run the script on file changes:
ls /path/to/local/folder/* | entr -d ./sync.sh




Using SSH within the Pod:

I tried setting up an SSH server within the pod to use RSYNC over SSH.
Steps taken:

Install OpenSSH Server in the Pod:
kubectl exec -it <pod-name> -- /bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y openssh-server
echo 'root:password' | sudo chpasswd
sudo sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh start


Expose SSH Port via a Kubernetes Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ssh-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: your-app-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 22
      targetPort: 22

kubectl apply -f ssh-service.yaml
kubectl get svc ssh-service


SSH into the Pod:
ssh root@<service-ip>


Configure RSYNC:
#!/bin/bash
LOCAL_DIR="/path/to/local/folder"
REMOTE_USER="root"
REMOTE_HOST="<service-ip>"
REMOTE_DIR="/path/to/remote/folder"
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p 22" $LOCAL_DIR $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_HOST:$REMOTE_DIR







I am looking for the best way to synchronize my files automatically on save in VSCode under these constraints. Any suggestions or improvements on these approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Why not use a purpose built tool? https://github.com/okteto/okteto?tab=readme-ov-file#how-it-works

If your Deployment has three replicas, which one are you manually copying files to?  If those files turn out to be broken, will your entire application go down with it?  It sounds like you're trying to do live development in a remote clustered environment, and that might not be a good match.  I might build and test your application locally with no container environment at all, then build an image and push it to a test cluster the same way you would any other code change (without using rsync, ssh, kubectl cp, ...).

If you want to run your code inside a k8s environment during development, I'd strongly suggest using https://tilt.dev - less pain, and there is not need to change your production deployment to accommodate development needs.

@OneCricketeer this look very promising! okteto accelerates the development workflow of Kubernetes applications. You write your code locally and okteto detects the changes and instantly updates your Kubernetes applications.. Do you mind providing an answer with your minimal workflow? Maybe a comment how it interacts if at all with vscode? That would be amazing. Happy to reward with the bounty too if it works ;)

I dont have a workflow, I am just aware of the tool, and it detects any local changes AFAIK, so could use any editor with it. There's also Bridge to Kubernetes plugin from Microsoft for VSCode that might do something similar

This question is not about a specific programming problem, but asking for a solution to a problem, more like asking for app or library suggestions or something along those lines. This is not likely to attract high-quality answers and really doesn't belong on SO. See also what topics can I ask about here and what types of question should I avoid asking. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Have you tried to edit files directly in your pod ? You can attach vscode to
a Pod thanks to the dev container extension that is part of the Remote Development Suite. You will also need to have the Kubernetes extenstion installed.
With those extensions, you can navigate to your pod and choose Attach Visual Studio Code from the context menu:

It will open a new vscode window and you will be able to edit the files inside the Pod directly:

You need to have enough of a user environment on the pod for vscode to be able to download the vscode server code and launch it, but since you are able to install ssh on the pod, I assume that this is the case.
AFAIK, vscode uses kubectl exec in order to manage the communication link between your machine and the pod. You need to be able to perform this kind of operation.
At my company, we routinely use this in order to test things inside the cluster. Note that the communication link is not as reliable as with ssh and in some cases we have deployed a ssh server as you suggest and used the remote ssh extension.
Once you have ssh access to your pod, you can consider mounting part of the pod filesystem locally using rclone.
